# Is that safe for data serialized in App with NSCoding?

Tags: iphone, ios, security, serialization, nscoding

here is the things: there are some data sensitive which be stored in the device using NSCoding serialization.

I'd like to know is there a way the other people can find the key and unarchived the serialized object file to get data?

Thanks for help.

Comment: may be if they are intelligent enough!

Answer (score 1):

It is not safe to store sensitive data just using NSCoding.  The NSCoded values are not encrypted in any way - you don't even need to know the keys - you can just look at a stored file directly and easily see the values if they are strings.

Sensitive data (particularly API access keys that provide privileged access to back-end web services or financial information) ideally should not be kept on the client device at all.  Even when encrypted.  In the extreme case, a black hat who has your app installed on their device can mount a man-in-the-middle attack and snoop on your internet traffic with your server.  Instead you should a device-specific token approach if concerned about security so you can revoke a token if necessary without affecting other users.

If *really* concerned, you should look at two factor authentication in addition to the token.

Here is an [intro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_token) for further reading.

Comment: Sorry - just realised this question is 10 months old.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Each application is given its own 'sandbox' on the filesystem. On a device that has not been jailbroken, an app cannot look outside of its own sandbox. However, when a user connects their device to a Mac or PC, it is possible to use utility applications such as iExplorer (http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) to access the sandbox of each app on their device.

Comment: I suppose they have already the binary data file. The question is if there is a way can deserialize the file and get data without keys.

Comment: If someone has access to your compiled app and your data file, I think it would be pretty easy to deserialize the data. Running your app through the 'strings' utility would probably quickly show the keys (if they're not already clearly visible in the data file).